# .class en clases genéricas

Tags: java, genericos

Necesito ayuda, no encuentro cómo se podría pasar a genérico esta clase:

```
@Component
public class DossierConverter {

 @Autowired
 private ModelMapper modelMapper;

 public DossierDTO convertToDto(Dossier entity) {
    DossierDTO resultDto =  modelMapper.map(entity, DossierDTO.class);

    return resultDto;
 }

 public Dossier convertToEntity(DossierDTO dossierDTO) {
    Dossier dossier = modelMapper.map(dossierDTO, Dossier.class);

    return dossier;
 }
}
```

Mi problema es que no sé cómo pasar ".class", ¿alguien tiene alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir? Puedes simplemente no usar la clase DossierConverter y usar ModelMapper directamente (si te fijas, no te ahorras ni una línea de código al usar esta clase)

Comment: Es que quería ponerlo en una clase a parte por si más adelante la usaba para hacer algo más complejo. Y cómo no encontraba lo del .class tenía curiosidad por aprender como se podía hacer.

Comment: Debes entender que ese `.class` no hace referencia a un archivo, si no a una [construcción del lenguaje](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2). ¿Qué error o problema tienes al compilar? ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor (con algún ejemplo) el uso que pretendes o lo que has intentado y te falla?